# Why am I obtaining this ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error calling an HTTPS API using a self signed certificate from an Angular service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, javascript-framework, angular-http

I have the following problem trying to call an external REST **HTTPS** API from an Angular service:

I have this Angular service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MailDetailProtocolloService {

    private protocolloAooApiUrl = 'https://myservercom:443/my_project/api/GetDeparmentsList';  

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    )
    {
    }

    /** GET AOO List chiamando un'API esterna */

    getAooList(): Observable<Aoo[]> {
        return this.http.get<Aoo[]>(this.protocolloAooApiUrl)
    }

}
```

The problem is that this API use a **self signed certificate** and calling it I obtain this error message in the console:

```
GET https://myservercom:443/my_project/api/GetDeparmentsList net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Why? How can I fix it and call it using this self signed certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-signed certificates aren't accepted by browsers per default. There is a list of trusted *certification authorities* (short 'CA') installed on your computer that are allowed to issue certificates. In order to have your computer trust your certificate, you have to either add your CA to this trust list manually or install the self-signed certificate directly.

How to do this depends on your operating system and browser.

[Here is the tutorial for Windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/)

[Here is the turorial for Mac](https://tosbourn.com/getting-os-x-to-trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates/)

[Here is the tutorial for Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list)

Unlike with "fat clients", there isn't any way to do this automatically with web applications; it's a default security policy for all modern browsers. Imagine a website could send sensitive data in the background to a malicious website.